# Display the same instance of a JTree using two different renderers at the same time

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm trying to visualize a diff tree, which represents the differences between two tree structures. Usually such visualizations use two instances of a component to display the left and right side with differences between them pointed out to the user, but in my case the actual result of the diffing algorithm is a single tree, where each node may take up to two different roles at the same time (left and right role).

It must appear to the user like there are two `JTree`s next to each other, side by side. How the implementation achieves this is irrelevant. My current approach is to use two synced `JTree` instances sharing the model. Is there another implementation approach, that would use a single `JTree` instance to achieve the same?

Two `JTree`s, SIDE BY SIDE, is a requirement.

This is not the type of question where I could provide a viable code example but here's a switchable renderer one that emulates my tree model:

```java
package org.stackoverflow.example;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class SameTreeNodesRenderedDifferently extends JFrame {
    
    private JTree tree;
    private JButton button;
    private MyTreeCellRenderer leftRenderer;
    private MyTreeCellRenderer rightRenderer;
    private MyTreeCellRenderer currentRenderer;
    
    public SameTreeNodesRenderedDifferently() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        setTitle("SameTreeNodesRenderedDifferently");
        
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("root"));
        createTree(root);
        tree = new JTree(root);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tree);
        add(scroll);
        
        leftRenderer = new MyTreeCellRenderer(true);
        rightRenderer = new MyTreeCellRenderer(false);
        currentRenderer = leftRenderer;
        tree.setCellRenderer(currentRenderer);
        expandAll();
        
        button = new JButton("Switch renderer");
        add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                currentRenderer = currentRenderer == leftRenderer ? rightRenderer : leftRenderer;
                tree.setCellRenderer(currentRenderer);
                tree.revalidate();
                tree.repaint();
                expandAll();
            }
        });
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
    private void createTree(DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode a = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("a"));
        root.add(a);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode b = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("b", "!b"));
        a.add(b);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode c = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("c"));
        a.add(c);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode d = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("d"));
        root.add(d);        
        DefaultMutableTreeNode e = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("e", "!e"));
        d.add(e);       
        DefaultMutableTreeNode f = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("f", "!f"));
        d.add(f);       
        DefaultMutableTreeNode g = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("g", "!g"));
        d.add(g);       
        DefaultMutableTreeNode h = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new MyNode("h"));
        d.add(h);
    }
    
    private void expandAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
            tree.expandRow(i);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SameTreeNodesRenderedDifferently().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    private static class MyTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

        private final boolean left;
        
        public MyTreeCellRenderer(boolean left) {
            this.left = left;
        }
        
        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
            if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode dmtn = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
                MyNode node = (MyNode) dmtn.getUserObject();
                setText(left ? node.leftValue : node.rightValue);
            }
            return this;
        }
        
    }
    
    public static class MyNode {
        private final String leftValue;
        private final String rightValue;
        
        public MyNode(String value) {
            this(value, value);
        }
        
        public MyNode(String leftValue, String rightValue) {
            this.leftValue = leftValue;
            this.rightValue = rightValue;
        }

        public String getLeftValue() {
            return leftValue;
        }

        public String getRightValue() {
            return rightValue;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyNode{" + "leftValue=" + leftValue + ", rightValue=" + rightValue + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still wondering: why go for "dirty" workarounds and a strange design, when you already know the "right" design (to use one model but two trees)?! You see: the **model** is the abstraction that is meant to be shared between UI components. You are trying to use a UI component for something that it isnt intended for ... why?

Comment: @GhostCat Because is seems to be a waste of resources. Internally, a JTree creates its own "default mutable tree model" for each tree, so more objects for the same thing. Plus managing two JTrees to be kept in sync is a delicate matter.

Comment: How much resources are you going to "waste" by doing it the right way? It's like some of the people here who are asking about how to optimize sorting an array of 100 int's.

Comment: @NomadMaker we are talking about a lot of objects that the user may create via a simple button press, recurringly. If I see room for optimization, I won't think twice. JTree itself uses a single cell renderer component instance to render each node. Why do you think that is?

Comment: Donald Knuth said "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." He expanded on this, and stated something like "If you absolutely have to optimize, you must use a profiler to determine where the optimization is needed." You are putting your effort into the wrong area.

Comment: @NomadMaker I get your point. I've put zero effort into this, I'm just checking if someone else might have done so.